# Can't see form data but app objects get the data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, post, google-chrome-devtools

I can't see POST request data after I click the "Savess" button. The request should appear like "Create". The form sends data to the "Create" ActionResult
[image: Chorme enviroment]
But the data from the form it's transmitted (or binded) into its corresponding object attributes.
[image: Inside Visual Studio]

Why is chrome not showing that request?

Comment: Is there a problem in the way I raised the question? I ask because someone voted down my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a recent bug in Chrome. It shows up when the status code is 302. See:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=766715

Comment: *Wasted 3 hours thinking I didn't understand POST or HTTP or 302 or Chrome or the Debugger or x-www-url-form-encoding anymore despite web developing for 10 years*

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. The thing I don't understand is why my question got voted down?